# Using a real number X calculate quadratic equation using only addition, multiplication and subtraction

Tags: polynomials

As I understand, that I cant use discriminant in here, but how to solve then?

> Given a real number X. Without the use of any other actions besides addition, multiplication and subtraction calculate:
>   $5x^4$+$2x^3$-$8x$-$1$

Comment: I don't get it: calculate *what*?! There is no equation there, only a polynomial...

Comment: "calculate this polynomial" does not make much sense... do you mean you want to find the solutions to $5x^4+2x^3-8x-1=0$? The discriminant uses only multiplication, and subtraction so I don't see how it's ruled out... but I also don't see how that would help you solve the equation...

Comment: its not ruled out, it's just I get the impression of that, because thers no =0 at the end so im kinda confused..

Comment: @EverWondeR If this is the exact wording, it's no wonder you can't solve it. It is not a valid statement of a question.

Comment: I removed the quadratic equation tag because it looks like it was mistakenly applied to a 4th degree polynomial.

Comment: That's not a quadratic equation, it is a polynomial, and it is not a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: If we were actually given a specific number, then we could calculate $5x^4+2x^3-8x-1$ using addition, multiplication and substraction, but it's a pretty trivial problem.

Comment: @EverWondeR A polynomial of degree 4 is called a *quartic* polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the common ways to evaluate such polynomials is to write it as:

$$((5\cdot x+2)\cdot x\cdot x - 8)\cdot x - 1$$

This trick is used because it minimizes the number of multiplications.

Compare that to a more straight-forward approach: pre-calculating $y=x\cdot x$ then writing the polynomial as:

$$5\cdot y\cdot y +2\cdot y\cdot x -8\cdot x -1$$

That takes six multiplications (including calculating $y$,) compared to a mere $4$ multiplications in my original formula.

Comment: Hah ... neat aspect!

Comment: Thank you! Simple and clear!

Comment: A general polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ in this way can be computed in $n$ multiplications and $n$ additions or subtractions. (Here, since one of the ceoffieients is zero, we have fewer additions.)

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to find the roots of the polynomial, then it won't be possible to do with only arithmetic operations: the solutions include square roots and cube roots.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want something like $-1 + x(-8 + x(x(2 + x(5))))$?

Answer (score 1):

As written, you just multiply $x$ together four times, multiply that by 5, multiply $x$ together three times, multiply that by $2$, add to the previous, and so on

More efficiently you could do $x(x\cdot x(5x+2)-8)-1$